# Unbalanced clusters Spectral Coclustering sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, svd

I'm following the Spectral Coclustering of documents and words tutorial on sklearn (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/bicluster/plot_bicluster_newsgroups.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-bicluster-plot-bicluster-newsgroups-py) and my clusters are very unbalanced. I have the output :

```
Vectorizing...
Coclustering...
Done in 7.20s. V-measure: 0.4267
MiniBatchKMeans...
Done in 9.13s. V-measure: 0.4414

Best biclusters:
----------------
bicluster 0 : 8 documents, 6 words
categories   : 100% talk.politics.mideast
words        : angmar, cosmo, alfalfa, alphalpha, proline, benson

bicluster 1 : 4 documents, 9 words
categories   : 100% comp.windows.x
words        : elin, eeam, ges, energeanwendung, penzingerstr, gesmbh, energieanwendung, hochreiter, wien

bicluster 2 : 14 documents, 33 words
categories   : 86% comp.windows.x, 14% talk.politics.mideast
words        : rpicas, porto, wg2, se05, libxmu, waii, xmu, picas, inescn, ep130

bicluster 3 : 2809 documents, 4242 words
categories   : 25% comp.windows.x, 21% comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware, 20% comp.graphics
words        : windows, scsi, motif, ide, graphics, pc, card, window, bmug, controller

bicluster 4 : 5166 documents, 5686 words
categories   : 16% rec.motorcycles, 15% rec.autos, 14% sci.electronics
words        : autos, motorcycles, bike, car, sale, engine, dod, bmw, engr, honda
```

I don't know why its different from the tutorial, but is there a solution to have more balanced clusters ?

I even code my "own" Spectral coclustering following [this link](http://www.kemaleren.com/post/spectral-biclustering-part-1/) and using the SVD from scipy.sparse.linalg and the Kmeans from sklearn, but I have the same problem...

Thank you !

Comment: When you run the example code from here (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/bicluster/plot_bicluster_newsgroups.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-bicluster-plot-bicluster-newsgroups-py) you get this output ???

Comment: Yes, but I am just loading the dataset with the sklearn.datasets.load_files after having downloaded it [here](http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/), as I'm behind a corporate firewall and I can't use the fetch_20newsgroups function. Perhaps it is not the same dataset...

Comment: Perhaps there are little clusters of documents and words that are totally disconnected from the others, and the SVD spots them first

Comment: Yes. That is the case. I just run the example code from the website and i got the same results.